# How to update multiple columns based on values from an associated table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sqldatetime, sql-limit

There are two tables named *masters* and *versions*. The *versions* table holds entries of the *master* table at different points in time.

```
-------------------------
 masters
-------------------------
 id |  name |  added_at
----+-------+------------
  1 | a-old | 2013-08-13
  2 | b-new | 2012-04-19
  3 | c-old | 2012-02-01
  4 | d-old | 2012-12-24
```

It is guaranteed that there is **at least one** *versions* entry for each *masters* entry.

```
---------------------------------------------   
 versions
---------------------------------------------
 id |  name |   added_at | notes | master_id
----+-------+--------------------------------
  1 | a-new | 2013-08-14 | lorem |         1
  1 | a-old | 2013-08-13 | lorem |         1
  2 | b-new | 2012-04-19 | lorem |         2
  3 | c-old | 2012-02-01 | lorem |         3
  4 | d-new | 2013-02-20 | lorem |         4
  5 | d-old | 2012-12-24 | lorem |         4
```

The tables can also be found in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cf9f/1).
The latest *version* of each *master* record can be selected as shown in this example for *masters* record `2`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM versions
WHERE master_id = 2
ORDER BY added_at DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

How can I update **each record** of the *masters* table with its **latest** *version* in **one command**? I want to overwrite the values for both the `name` and `added_at` columns. Please note, there are additional columns in the *versions* table which do not exist in the *masters* table such as `notes`.

Can the update been done with a `JOIN` so it performs fast on larger tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to fire subquery twice.

- [Here is SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e56eb9/1)

Below is the update statement

```
update masters m, (
  select id, name, added_at, master_id 
  from versions 
  order by added_at desc
) V
set
  m.name = v.name, 
  m.added_at = v.added_at     
where v.master_id = m.id;
```

Comment: I removed the parts matching the specific `..id = 2`. Running your example then misses to update *masters* row with `id` = `4`, `d-old` for some reason.

Comment: Now check [this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e56eb9/1). if its correct then i will modify the post

Comment: Looks good. It seems to also work with additional columns as I introduced them to my question in the meantime. Please update your answer. Btw: Typo in "Fiddel".

Comment: @JJD I have  modified my post. Look at it.

Comment: Your solution has the advantage that the *masters* table can contain **additional columns**. (+1) Though explicitely defining each pair such as `m.name = v.name` makes it a bit unflexible for changing columns in the future.

Comment: If my post is what you were searching for then you can accept it.

Comment: I intend doing this and I am thankful for your help. But let's wait if somebody comes up with a solution using `JOIN` and without using the pair definition as I mentioned. I will leave the question open for at least one day.

Comment: Instead of `,` simply replace with `join` an check

Comment: I am not sure if I get you right.. I was talking about `INNER JOIN` or similar...

Answer (score 1):

This might do what you need:

```
REPLACE INTO masters
    SELECT v.master_id,v.name,v.added_at 
    FROM versions v 
    WHERE v.added_at = (SELECT MAX(vi.added_at) 
                       FROM versions vi 
                       WHERE  vi.master_id = v.master_id);
```

Note that this relies on masters having a primary key on id and is MySQL specific.

Comment: This generates duplicates in the *masters* table.

Comment: @JJD Does the masters table have a Primary key? I noted that this wont work without one.

Comment: Thanks! I added `PRIMARY KEY` to the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Does this also work when I want to **update specific columns**? I revised my question to include this fact.

Comment: @JJD No, this won't work since it wont bring over the `note` column. One of the other answers would probably need to be used in that case.

Comment: And if it is the other way around: Does your solution work when *versions* has **more columns** then *masters* and I only want to update those which exist in *masters*?

Comment: @JDD. Yes, the select would only select the columns from versions that you need so versions could have more columns.

Answer (score 0):

Can't test it on mysql right now, but this should work on MSSQL

```
UPDATE masters AS m
SET 
  m.name = 
     (SELECT v.Name FROM versions AS v WHERE v.id = m.id AND v.added_at = 
     (SELECT MAX(v2.added_at) FROM versions As v2 WHERE v2.id = v.id))
  m.added_at = 
     (SELECT v.added_at FROM versions AS v3 WHERE v3.id = m.id AND v3.added_at = 
     (SELECT MAX(v4.added_at) FROM versions As v4 WHERE v4.id = v3.id))
```

Comment: I would like to avoid running a separate `SELECT` statements for each individual column.

Answer (score 0):

```
update masters set 
name = (SELECT name FROM versions
       WHERE master_id = masters.id
       ORDER BY added_at DESC
       LIMIT 1),
added_at = (SELECT added_at FROM versions
        WHERE master_id = masters.id
        ORDER BY added_at DESC
        LIMIT 1)
where id = 2;
```

Comment: I would like to avoid running a separate `SELECT` statements for each individual column.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you, try this:

```
UPDATE masters m 
SET m.name = (SELECT v.name FROM versions v WHERE
m.id = v.master_id ORDER BY v.added_at DESC LIMIT 1), 
m.added_at =
(SELECT v.added_at FROM versions v WHERE m.id = v.master_id ORDER BY
v.added_at DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: I would like to avoid running a separate `SELECT` statements for each individual column.